# JupyterLab | stdin user input via. shell. Entry into output cell field

Tags: python, shell, google-colaboratory, stdin, jupyter-lab

`Google Colab` allows you to enter values into an output cell, during runtime.

**Can I enter in user input, when calling a program via. the shell?**

**Can JupyterLab handle stdin from the shell?**

Example:

Cell: `!tensorboard dev upload --logdir tb_logs --name "OntologyTagger" --description "OntologyTagger" --one_shot`

Output: `Continue? (yes/NO)`, I click a text field and enter text.
[image]

---

**How can I do this in `JupyterLab`?**

JupyterLab:
[image]

Comment: This question was answered in https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10881#issuecomment-903005097, which highlights that a solution would need to be implemented in the kernel itself, and that there is an open issue discussing it in https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/513. It looks like a godd first issue to me if anyone would like to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is provided using input method of python. So whenever you wanted to wait till user provide some kind of input during execution of the program use input method.

```
name = input('Provide your name\n')
```

When we run this code inside jupyter lab or jupyter notebook cell it will wait till we provide input into it.

**Keep note** Whatever data we pass it's datatype is string so if you are taking numerically data as input make sure to type cast it.

Comment: Hey thanks for posting an answer. What cells do I place this into? When, during the runtime? What variable name do I give it? I assume it would be `my_input = input('yes\n')`.

Comment: You can use put into any cell in which you want to take input during runtime. Variable name is totally up to you no restriction on it.

Comment: new cell: `in_continue = input('yes\n')` is stuck on `[*]`. It is right above cell that requires input.

Comment: Upon research; string param for `input()` is a prompt to the user.. not a means of entering in a value to a cell (in the sense that I'm after). I hope my post makes sense.

Comment: I was in assumption that you want hold current cell execution in between then take input from user and based on that input execute next step on same cell.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally edited your answer. Please ignore.

Comment: Updated post title is the best way I can describe this feature, that I'm having problems with.

Comment: I learnt the technical jargon! I've updated my post asking better questions.